# How well is Debian supported on MIPS these days?

Tags: linux, debian, embedded, mips

I am doing a new embedded Linux design, and am thinking of using a MIPS CPU.  All my previous designs have used ARM.  On the most recent ARM design we installed Debian ARM-HF which was excellent.

My question is, are there pre-existing Debian installs for MIPS that can be easily installed on an embedded target?  With Debian ARM-HF installation was as easy as unzipping the pre-built filesystem.  Is MIPS likely to be supported for a long time to come?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should probably ask about this on the relevant debian forum/mailing list.